# play sound while recording fails

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, record

I have a 3rd party SDK that handles an audio recording. It has a callback when the recording starts. In the callback I'm trying to play a sound to indicate to the user that the device is now listening (like Siri, or any other speech recognition tends to do), but when I try I get the following error:

AURemoteIO::ChangeHardwareFormats: error -10875

I have tried playing the sound using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound as well as an AVAudioPlayer both with the same result. The sound plays fine at other times, and per the error my assumption is there's an incompatibility between the playback and recording on the hardware level. Can anyone clarify this error, or give me a hint as to a possible workaround?

Comment: I have since discovered that the SDK has a way to que a sound for playback when the recording starts!... only it doesn't work right. It plays when you ask the recording to start, not when it actually starts so it's pointless and I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is related specifically to the external SDK and how they handle the audio interface. They override everything when you ask the SDK to start recording, if you take control back you break the recording session. So within the context of that SDK there's no way to work around it unless they fix the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Audio Session is initialised and configured for Play_and_Record before you start the RemoteIO Audio Unit recording.

Comment: It is inited for play and record by me prior to the 3rd party SDK call. Perhaps they're changing it internally to just record? is this the error one should expect if they were to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't and likely can't start playing a sound in a RemoteIO recording callback.  Only set a boolean flag in the callback to indicate that a sound should be played.  Play your sound from the main UI run loop.

Comment: The callback executes on the main thread. I have since attempted to play the sound from a child thread, and with a delay, and explicitly on the main thread (just incase I was wrong and it wasn't on the main thread to begin with) in an attempt to get around any thread relating hiccups but with no effect. I seems related to the audio hardware itself.